# Rails - how to strip forward slash characters from data in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that I've converted over from another cms. The old URLs were being stored in the database like so:

```
/this-is-an-old-permalink/
```

And I need them to be like this:

```
this-is-an-old-permalink
```

Note the absence of forward slashes. What is the easiest way to go about removing them?

I'm not necessarily looking for the exact code to do it (although that'd be nice!) -- I'm asking also as a Rails newb: What is the best method to go about doing things like this? I've only really worked with Rails in setting up a model, controller, views and outputting data. I haven't had to do any processing like this. Would it go in the model? Any help is appreciated!

---

**edit**

Do I need to get all records, loop through them, do regex on that one field and then save it?

Comment: Processing the items within a model the "Rails way" is generally achieved using Modelname.find_all do { block here }. In this case, the block would contain code that would gsub on each instance of the model (each "row"), then write that instance back to the store (in this case, update the row in the database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're likely only going to write this once, your best bet is to create a script for it within lib, or to write a migration for it. I recommend the latter, because it will then be executed automatically with rake db:migrate if you restore from your old backup at a later date. You can then use all your standard Model processing tricks (like you would use on a Controller) within the migration without exposing the substitution code to a Controller.

EDIT:

You can add the following to a new file within lib/tasks to create a new rake task for this called db:substitute_slashes:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Remove slashes from old-style URLs"
  task :substitute_slashes => :environment do
    Modelname.find(:all).each do |obj|
      obj.fieldname.gsub!(/regex here/,'')
      obj.save!
    end
  end
end
```

The exclamation on the end of save! means it will throw an exception if the resulting object fails validation, which is a good thing to check for in this case.

You would then be able to execute this with the command rake db:substitute_slashes.

Comment: I'm actually doing a data migration (using navicat) and putting the data into the database only once. So now I'm stuck with the data in the database with the slashes. So in that case, you're saying create a script for it in lib? Is that in /lib/tasks ? (Remember, I'm a complete newb) :-)

Comment: I've modified my answer with more info. The regex you will use will depend on the actual structure of the data, like whether or not the forward slashes are escaped.

Comment: +1 this is awesome, sets me on the right track for sure. I had to change .find_all to .all. -- No matter what I try putting in the regex section I'm not getting the desired result. But this definitely puts me in a good spot. Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the code of the old CMS, you might try to check out the snippet that processes those URLs--odds are it'll give you a regex that you might even be able to rip directly.

Comment: I made a quick edit on a typo I made--it should be find(:all).each, not find_all (find_all is the old way, and the each is there to enumerate)